# Tagging with Select2 Multiple Widget in Django?

Tags: django, jquery-select2, django-1.9

I'm using the `django-select2` django module, and the `django_select2.forms.Select2MultipleWidget` widget:

```
langs = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Languages (Subdomains)",
                                  widget=django_select2.forms.Select2MultipleWidget(
                                  attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Please choose languages'} ))
```

How can I enable tagging? By [select2 docs](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags), it's possible when passing `'tags': true` to the Select2 initiator.

Thanks

Comment: you answer your own question in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on [Django-Select2's Docs](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html#module-django_select2.forms), I need to use a widget that inherits both `SelectMultiple` and `Select2TagMixin`:
[image]

Therefore the correct widget should be `Select2TagWidget`.

Comment: Hey, could you share your work, I am a beginner and I totally fed up working with it.